# Get absolute file path on IOS with Flutter

Tags: ios, file, flutter, path

In my Flutter App I would like to have a possibility to link paths to the files located on the device or in some clod (GDrive, DropBox, iCloud) to open them later on.

I tried to use file_picker plug-in but it does not really work how I would need:
- it copies files to the temp directory, so files stay there for a while and are removed automatically by the OS, which is especially painful on Apple devices
- I do not get absolute paths to files but only to a local App's one after they are copied to temp

I also tried filesystem_picker plugin but it does not work under iOS out of the box sayin permission is not granted.

Is there any way to:
- get global path to files?
- not to copy files to the temp directory rather to open them using global path

Thanks in advance!

Comment: tried that one? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_absolute_path#-example-tab-

Comment: this plugin does not compile. Looks like it has not been update fro more than a year...

Comment: It published less than one year ago and i used it approximately 3-4 months ago but I get your point, if it doesn't work currently you can check this one it is newer, https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

Comment: I started with file_picker but  somehow it does not work in ipone - I cannot get files from cloud and the local one are always copied to temp directory. I want to get absolute path and open file from where it's stored without coping it.

Comment: @Fellow7000 Have you find any solution for above? I want to play song after select from file_picker but not getting full path in IOS.

Comment: @himanshu no, for IOS I've found anything yet and had to exclude this feature from my App. If you find anything better, please let me know. Thanks! :)(

Comment: @himanshu, no I finally decided to drop this feature on iOS version of the app